# Sum all transaction by current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a transaction model

```
create_table "transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "hire_id"
    t.bigint "withdraw_id"
    t.bigint "user_by_id"
    t.bigint "user_to_id"
    t.string "reference"
    t.integer "status"
    t.integer "price"
    t.integer "transaction_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["hire_id"], name: "index_transactions_on_hire_id"
    t.index ["user_by_id"], name: "index_transactions_on_user_by_id"
    t.index ["user_to_id"], name: "index_transactions_on_user_to_id"
    t.index ["withdraw_id"], name: "index_transactions_on_withdraw_id"
 end
```

Transaction_type is an enum, so I have this on my transaction controller

```
@debit = Transaction.where(transaction_type: "Debit").sum(:price)
@credit = Transaction.where(transaction_type: "Credit").sum(:price)
```

I want to generate the total credit and debit of current_user (current_user.id==user_by_id)

How can I do it, please?

I have tried to do

```
@total_credit_by_user = @credit.group_by(&:user_by_id).sum(:price)
@total_debit_by_user = @debit.group_by(&:user_by_id).sum(:price)
```

and in my view, I have

```
<%= @total_credit_by_user[current_user.id] %>
<%= @total_debit_by_user[current_user.id] %>
```

But I am getting `undefined method` +' for :price:Symbol`

How can I sum the total credit and debit by a current_user when current_user.id==user_by_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they appear similar, the [sum](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/Enumerable/sum) method for a Hash is different than the [sum](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Calculations/sum) method for an ActiveRecord relation. Calling `group_by` on a relation returns a Hash object, whose `sum` method does not accept a column name as an argument. You can use [group](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group) instead, which will perform a `GROUP BY` and allow you to use `sum` on the ActiveRecord relation.

In this case, if you need a map of the total credit amounts per user, you can update the controller logic to use `group` in conjunction with `sum`, like so:

```rb
credits = Transaction.where(transaction_type: "Credit")
@total_credit_by_user = credits.group(:user_by_id).sum(:price)
```

You can then access the total credits for the desired user by passing in their ID:

```rb
@total_credit_by_user[current_user.id]
```

If you only want to fetch the total credit amount for the current user you can modify the above query to the following:

```rb
@total_credit = credits.where(user_by_id: current_user.id).sum(:price)
```

Then you can use the `@total_credit` value in the view directly.